# Docker not extracting .tar.gz and cannot find the file in the image

Tags: linux, docker

I am having trouble with extracting a .tar.gz file and accessing its files on a docker image. I've tried looking around Stackoverflow, but the solutions didn't fix my problem... Below is my folder structure and my Dockerfile. I've made an image called `modus`.

Folder structure:

```
- modus
    Dockerfile
    ModusToolbox_2.1.0.1266-linux-install.tar.gz
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

USER root
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install git -y 
COPY ./ModusToolbox_2.1.0.1266-linux-install.tar.gz /root/
RUN cd /root/ && tar -C /root/ -zxzf ModusToolbox_2.1.0.1266-linux-install.tar.gz
```

I've been running the commands below, but when I try to check /root/ the extracted files aren't there...

```
docker build .
docker run -it modus
  root@e19d081664e4:/# cd root
  root@e19d081664e4:/# ls
  <prints nothing>
```

There should be a folder called ModusToolBox, but I can't find it anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

P.S
I have tried changing ADD to COPY, but both don't work.

Comment: Works for me. Why are you running `docker run -it modus`? You didn't provide image title. Docker should say something like `Successfully built aa24b18669c1` at the end of the build, run `docker run -it   aa24b18669c1`

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I was just running the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a tag option with `-t` but you're using a tag in
`docker run -it modus`. By doing that you run some other `modus` image, not the one you have just built. Docker should say something
like `Successfully built <IMAGE_ID>` at the end of the build, run
`docker run -it <IMAGE_ID>` to run a newly built image if you don't want to provide a tag.